# Change mouse pointer when dragging in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page where I have built a simple drag and drop scheme.  I have used user-select:none to keep the text from being selected as I drag, and set cursor:pointer to keep the text-select bar from appearing when the user mouses over text.  Unfortunately, when they hold the mouse button and drag an item around, the pointer changes to the I bar as if they were currently selecting text.  Is there any way to change this behavior?   Thanks!

Comment: add a class to a dragged element and set rules on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to change this behavior?

Yes. You need to call prevent default on the mouse down event when you detect the user dragging the appropriate item.

Comment: This seems like it's what I want, but not working.  Here's my function: `$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (dragInProcess) {
                $('#dragItem').position({
                    my: "left center",
                    of: e,
                    offset: "3 -3"
                });
            };`

Comment: @JoshuaSmith, whoops, mistake on my part, should have been `mousedown` event. You may need to additionally change the css cursor property if you are hovering over text.

Comment: this also disables scrolling the page with the mouse for me

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I implement drag-and-drop, I place a mask over the entire page to capture the `mousemove` event wherever it may be. This mask has the relevant cursor set, usually `cursor: move;`.